# Evaluating methods inside a function, where the method arguments have not been passed

Tags: python, parameter-passing, sympy

Consider the following Python3 code, where I define the function f(t)^2 and differentiate it:

```
import sympy as sp


def differentiate(func):
    return func.diff(arg)


fct = sp.symbols('f', cls=sp.Function)
arg = sp.symbols('t')

expr = fct(arg) ** 2

print(differentiate(expr))  # returns 2*f(t)*Derivative(f(t), t)
```

My question is, why is it not necessary to also pass the name of the Python variable, `arg`, to the `differentiate` function?

(I'm only passing the expression `expr`, which I believe is an object sympy creates for me. How does the method diff applied to this know about `arg`?)

Comment: Well, you are passing `arg` to `func.diff` in `differentiate`. Since `differentiate` doesn't have this argument itself, it will try to search for the name in the outer scope, where `arg` exists at the moment you call `differentiate`. This is generally considered a bad practice in most scenarios, except closures (i.e. binding a nested function to a local variable inside a parent-function).

Comment: @EliKorvigo I don't really understand your answer, what is `differentiate`? The `diff` method basically returns the `Derivative` class, which carries out the differentiation. Also, what would a good practice look like? Using something like `t=expr.free_symbol` inside the function? Since this is redundant, I assume not.

Comment: `differentiate` is a your own function, isn't it? The one you define early in your example. This function returns the result of `func.diff(arg)`. From `differentiate`'s point of view, `func` is an argument and `arg` is a name from an outer scope (it is so, because `differentiate` doesn't have such an argument). This is a bad practice, because your function `differentiate` is bound to a non-constant entity from an outer scope, which also happens to be the global name-space. In other words, your function `differentiate` depends on a global variable, which leads to all sorts of trouble.

Comment: @EliKorvigo Ah, sorry, I was in "the wrong movie" as they say and somehow was looking for `differentiate` in sympy's classes and coudln't reconcile thst with your explanation. Now everything's clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To the other answer I would add that this has nothing to do with SymPy. This is just how Python works. If a function references a variable that isn't defined in that function, it gets it from the outer namespace where the function is defined (you can search this site or the web for "Python scoping" for more information about this).

This "worked" because you also used the variable name `arg` for `symbols('t')`. In general, I would recommend naming SymPy variables the same as their symbol name, so instead of `arg`, use

```
t = symbols('t')
```

You will avoid a lot of headache if you always do this.

Answer (score 3):

I think this is just bad code as it relies upon a global variable `arg` while it should be one of `differentiate`'s arguments. If you call this variable `argument`, for example, the function won't work.

This code works because `arg` is a *global* variable, accessible to any function. So, the interpreter 'sees' the usage of the name `arg` in the function and asks itself: "is there a variable called `arg` in the local scope?" - nope; "is there a variable called `arg` in the *global* scope?" - yep; so, it takes it and passes as an argument to `func.diff`.